# Postgres comparing two databases

Tags: postgresql

We running two database servers with around 10 databases and multiple schemas in it (production and test). Every night we restore some of the prod to the test. The backup we do with pg_dump and restore with pg_restore. Now the size of the production and the restored database differnces from a few kb up to 700mb.

Now I want to ensure that the restored data is the same as on the production. I already saw that this is usual to postgres but we have to proof this to our manager. What would be the easiest to proof that the database servers are the same after the restore?

Comment: Is it possible that the new restored database is "clean" (like as if it has just a Vacuum performed)?  Hence the size difference.

Comment: Create a procedure to count the number of registries in each table on both databases after the export/import procedure. This will only work if there is no ongoing operation in the production/test databases.

Comment: @JorgeCampos : relying on counts can only tell you the refresh didn't work but can absolutely not inform about the success.

Comment: already tried to perform a Vacuum on prod, then back and restore on test. Even after that the size is different. I randomly picked few schemas and tables to compare manual - all of the matched. But this would not be accepted by the managment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just solved the provide our solution for the moment.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#change to the dir this script is located in (just to be sure)
cd "$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

# CONFIGURATION
remoteHost=stackoverflow.com
remotePort=5432
remoteUser=postgres
logfile=00comparsion.txt
#######################
cat "" > $logfile
databases=$(psql -U postgres -t -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false")
for database in $databases; do
    echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------  >> $logfile
    echo $database >> $logfile
    echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    echo $database
    if [ "$(psql -U $remoteUser -h $remoteHost -p $remotePort -tAc "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname='$database'" )" = '' ]
    then
        echo "Database '$database' does not exist on remote host! I quit now!"  >> $logfile
        exit 3
    fi
    schemas=$(psql -U postgres -d $database -t -c "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM information_schema.schemata
                                                    WHERE SCHEMA_NAME NOT IN ('pg_toast',
                                                                              'pg_temp_1',
                                                                              'pg_toast_temp_1',
                                                                              'pg_catalog',
                                                                              'information_schema')")

    for schema in $schemas; do
        echo --$schema  >> $logfile
        if [ "$(psql -U $remoteUser -h $remoteHost -p $remotePort -tAc "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM information_schema.schemata
                                                    WHERE SCHEMA_NAME='$schema'" )" = '' ]
        then
            echo "Schema '$schema' does not exist on remote host! I quit now!" >> $logfile
            exit 3
        fi
        tables=$(psql -U postgres -d $database -t -c "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables
                                                        WHERE table_schema = '$schema'")
        for table in $tables; do
            if [ "$(psql -U $remoteUser -h $remoteHost -p $remotePort -tAc "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables
                                                        WHERE table_name = '$table'" )" = '' ]
            then
                echo "table '$table' does not exist on remote host! I quit now!"  >> $logfile
                exit 3
            fi
            orderField=$(psql -U postgres -d $database -t -c "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns
                                                                WHERE table_schema = '$schema'
                                                                  AND table_name   = '$table' LIMIT 1")

            #psql -U postgres -d $database -t -c "SELECT * FROM $table order by $orderField" > l.txt
            #fetch same table data on remote instance
            #psql -U $remoteUser -h $remoteHost -p $remotePort -d $database -t -c "SELECT * FROM $table order by $orderField" > r.txt
            #if !(cmp --print-chars "l.txt" "r.txt")
            lcl=$(psql -U postgres -d $database -t -c "SELECT * FROM $table order by $orderField")
            rmt=$(psql -U $remoteUser -h $remoteHost -p $remotePort -d $database -t -c "SELECT * FROM $table order by $orderField")
            if !("$lcl"="$rmt")
            then
               echo ---$table ✘  >> $logfile
               exit 3
            else
               echo ---$table ✔  >> $logfile
            fi          
        done
    done
done
rm l.txt r.txt
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- >> $logfile
echo comparsion finished, sir! >> $logfile
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest you another approach. You can use `pg_restore` with `single transaction`. Quote from de [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html):

> 1
>   --single-transaction
>  Execute the restore as a single transaction (that is, wrap the emitted commands in BEGIN/COMMIT). This ensures that
>   either all the commands complete successfully, or no changes are
>   applied. This option implies --exit-on-error.

In this case you don't need to compare a `COUNT` on all tables from both sides just because if pg_restore returned 0 (zero) then everything went  well.

Comment: already tried this and seems to work. The concern we got is that we can no ensure that both servers contain the same data - this i have to proof some how to our managers